# In RSpec, how to prepend a before hook in a subcontext that accesses the subject?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Consider the following:

```
describe MyModel do
  context 'updates fields' do
    subject { create(:my_model) }
    before do
      subject.save
      subject.reload
    end

    context 'when changing foo.bar' do
      before { subject.foo.bar = 3 }
      it { is_expected.to be_multiple_bar }
    end

    context 'when changing baz.quux' do
      before { subject.baz.quux = 3 }
      it { is_expected.to be_multiple_quux }
    end
  end
end
```

Now, as you may expect, I want the `before` hook on line 4 to be invoked *after* the ones on lines 10 and 15.

I've tried 2 things:

1. I have tried using `prepend_before`, but that only works when they're defined in the same context, it doesn't allow you to prepend a hook before one that's defined in the supercontext
2. I have tried using `before(:context)` on line 10 and 15, and while this should put them in the right order, RSpec doesn't allow me to mutate the subject at that point yet. (And for good reason, I'm not trying to create a shared state here.)

I really don't want to resort to `let(:append_before) { proc { #magic here } }`, because it's ugly and hacky as hell. Besides, I think what I want is totally reasonable. Right now I copied the two lines over to all subcontexts, which I am not too happy with.

What is a better way to do this?

I am on RSpec 3.7, FactoryGirl 4.8.0 and Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: You ever figure it out?

Comment: No. I ended up refactoring enormously after figuring: 1. if my spec is simple, this would be a non-issue as it saves me 1 or 2 lines of code, and 2. if my spec is complicated, this would be a non-solution since it makes it even more obscure.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what your factory looks like, but instead to creating and persisting my_model, modifying, saving and reloading it, you should create it only once. This will also speed up your specs.

You could write something like this:

```
describe MyModel do
  context 'updates fields' do
    subject { create(:my_model, foo: {bar: bar}, baz: {quux: quux}) }

    context 'when changing foo.bar' do
      let(:bar) { 3 }
      it { is_expected.to be_multiple_bar }
    end

    context 'when changing baz.quux' do
      let(:quux) { 3 }
      it { is_expected.to be_multiple_quux }
    end
  end
end
```

Lazy evaluation of both let and subject makes sure you all your parameters are set correctly depending on the context. In case you need/want to extend your factory to support that, check out http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The point of my question however is in the context: it's about what happens when the update is called. I may be speccing an `on: :update` callback on the model. In your spec, it doesn't update the fields any more.

Comment: I see. If you are going to write integration specs, that's totally fine. In a unit test, checking if the callback exists is sufficient, since you don't want to test Rails. You could check if `MyModel._save_callbacks` contains the expected after or before save filter (e.g. `after_save :do_the_magic, on: :update`) without actually having to update the record. I don't think you should change RSpecs default behaviour for multiple reasons. Maybe post some more example code here to help understand the underlaying issue...